# Search for .Net Library to Generate chm files

Tags: .net, chm

I'm looking for a tool that will make it easy to create a chm file.

I don't need an IDE; want to handle it all through code.  Don't need to import content from .Net assemblies or database schema.

So this library would have methods like

NewProject()
AddTopic()
GetTopic()
ReIndex()
OutputToCHM()
Etc()

The only thing I can find that is close is From [WestWind](http://www.west-wind.com/wwhelp/) Software.  But I don't need all that additional functionality for $299.

Comment: Did any of the 17 answers to this question help you? [What are good tools for creating compiled html help files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023/what-are-good-tools-for-creating-compiled-html-help-files-chm)

Comment: Something like FAR would work, but then I'll have to create the HTML files first, then have the tool combine them into the final output.  But I'd really like to bypass the HTML generation part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandcastle is a great tool, especially with the Sandcastle Help File Builder, but this is an IDE rather than a library.

However, there is [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winhelp/SandcastleConceptual.aspx) on the CodeProject web site. I must confess that I have never used it, but it appears to be able to assist in compiling the CHM file. Regarding the actual topic files, I think it requires you to create them.

I hope this is of some use!

Comment: Looks like sandcastle is the way to go.  Time for the deep dive!

Comment: The Sandcastle Help File Builder really simplifies the content creation as it provides loads of helpful comments for all the document types. It can be downloaded for free from http://shfb.codeplex.com/. Also, the library on the CodeProject page contains a large number of example documents demonstrating the majority of the Sandcastle features.

Comment: Does Sandcastle generate CHM at all, or only .hhp projects to be compiled with the normal MS helpfile compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [SandCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)?

I know that it has an IDE and that it generates chm files from assemblies. But it is also open source so with a bit of hacing you might be able to save those 299$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Sandcastle.  But would really like a simpler api to work with.  I'm looking at it, though, so thanks.